# CouchDB changes feed seq shift

Tags: couchdb, nosql

I am new to CouchDB and assuming my _changes feed contains 8000 lines with the last_seq being 8000. Then I update a document (which has been previously updated with seq=4000-xxxx, rev=1-xxxxx) and it will be reflected on the changes feed as seq=8001-xxxx, rev=2-xxxx right?

My question is how does CouchDB handles this in fact? When I update document, it gets the latest seq id (8001-xxxx) but which doc takes its old place (seq 4000-xxxx)? And since we are updating stuff and there is only one entry per document how did the lines in changes feed rises from 8000 to 8001?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the latest changes made on a document not necessary will get the latest_seq + 1 in the _changes feed in Cloudant as detailed here.

https://gist.github.com/smithsz/30fb97662c549061e581

Answer (score 2):

Steven.

When you update a document, it is *moved* into the end of the seq queue. So there will be "holes" in your sequence index where the old document used to be.

In your example, the changes feed will show 8,000 lines, `last_seq` = 8001, and you will see seq 1, 2, 3, ..., 3997, 3998, 3999, 4001, 4002, 4003, ..., 7999, 8000, 8001. Note that 4000 is missing from the sequence.

This "move" is guaranteed to be atomic; so if you query _changes, then you will see either seq 4000 populated, or 8001 populated but not both. Every document ID is in the sequence index exactly once.

(Small note, if you query _changes *continuously*, with `?feed=continuous` then of course you can see duplicate document IDs, because CouchDB is giving you a real-time feed any time a document gets updated.)

Comment: Here's the weird thing, using the same example if I update a document it goes to 8001, but its old sequence 4000 is not missing, instead it is occupied by another document, which baffles me. I am using Cloudant BTW.

Comment: And furthermore, sometimes after I made a change to a document, the changes is not even on the latest seq id. I am not sure if this is a Cloudant-specific issue.